# VBA : Sub or Function Not Defined Compiler Error While Using Search

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I am very much stuck , i tied searching but i am not getting satisfactory solution

#### Below is my code

```
Dim i As Integer    
Dim k As Integer    
Dim Values As String    
Dim x As String

Worksheets("Pivot").Activate

Values = Range("B3").Value    
'Values = Mid(Values, 5, 16)    
'k = Search("|", Values)

x = Mid(Value, Search("|", Value) + 1, Search("|", Value, Search("|", Value) + 1) - Search("|", Value) - 1)))

MsgBox "" & x
```

#### Note :

The Error is "Sub or Function not defined " , I am getting this compiler error only if i use search formula , when i use Mid formula (the one that is commented i am not getting the error " anyone has any solution that can help me . 
In the Code i am trying to extract the string contained in a cell between occurrence of "|" contained in the entire string in the  cell .

Comment: Your variables do not match with the variables you set, Values Vs Value.

Comment: `Search` does not exist in vba, use [instr](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php)

Comment: actually use: `x=split(Values,"|")(1)` to return the value between the first and second `|`

Comment: The VBE should be highlighting precisely what's wrong with your code. Is `Option Explicit` specified at the top of the module?

Answer (score 1):

Search is a worksheet function.  It's equivilent in vba is Instr.

But in this case using Split will return what you want with less effort:

```
Dim Values As String    
Dim x As String

Values = Worksheets("Pivot").Range("B3").Value 

x=split(Values,"|")(1)

MsgBox "" & x
```